# What game ideas do you recommend for a newbie to begin his quest for game development?

Tags: c++, c, oop

I know that this is a subjective question.. But I don't know where else to ask but here. What game ideas do you recommend for someone who has not yet programmed any game yet? I would want to start with a very basic game.

Comment: Start with Construct2 and have a look through the tutorials and examples

Comment: A good starter game is the hanged man. You'll have to deal with string, numeric, input/output, and some drawing.

Comment: _I know that this is a subjective question.. But I don't know where else to ask but here._ -- If you knew that pick-pocketing was illegal, would you practice it at the police station?

Comment: Look for any eighties-era games - Pac-Man, Asteroids, Space Invaders, and so on. There will be movies on youtube and detailed descriptions online. If you want even simpler, then 15 puzzle or noughts-and-crosses, perhaps. Most importantly, pick one that doesn't bore you to tears before you've even started.

Answer (score 2):

I would start with a scroll and shoot aka [shoot'em up game](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoot_%27em_up) game. Such 2D games are more ore less easy to program and make fun without too much effort for level design etc.